# What is the fastest way to see when the last update to MongoDB was made

Tags: mongodb, long-polling

I'm writing a long-polling script to check for new documents in my mongo collection and the only way I know of checking to see whether or not changes have been made in the past iteration of my loop is to do a query getting the last document's ID and parsing out the timestamp in that ID and seeing if it's greater than the timestamp left since I last made a request.

Is there some kind of approach that doesn't involve making a query every time or something that makes that query the fastest?

I was thinking a query like this:

```
db.chat.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);
```

But it would be using the PHP driver.

Comment: By pulling latest document ID you will find latest insert, but won't catch latest update to existing document. Is this what you want?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I want the latest insert. These documents are not going to be updated assuming it's going to work the way I think it will. But either should work for my purposes, I think.

Comment: In this case the query should be fast enough. `_id` field is indexed. Anyway, how are you going to get data without a query of some sort?

Comment: Is there a performance problem with your query? What does it look like, by the way?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That makes sense I guess. I'm pretty new to this sort of thing. I just want it to be as fast as possible because I'm trying to build a chatroom that may have a couple hundred users each doing this iteration every 10ms. I don't even know if what I'm trying is practical.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I added what kind of a query I was thinking of doing to my question.

Comment: `db.chat.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)`; - it very bad design. use `findOne()` instead

Comment: @KevinBeal put here your collection document sample. `db.collection.findOne()`

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry I don't have one yet, but it's going to probably only have a single level array with maybe 5 items (including the _id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way will be creating indexes on `timestamp` field.

`Creating index:`

```
db.posts.ensureIndex( { timestamp : 1 } )
```

`Optimizes this query:`

```
db.posts.find().sort( { timestamp : -1 } )
```

`findOne` give you only one the last timestamp.

nice to help you.

Answer (score 0):

@Zagorulkin Your suggestion is surely going to help in the required scenario. However i don't think so sort() works with findOne().